# create_module - why is copy_from_user used?

Tags: c, module, linux-kernel, kernel, vmalloc

I'm reading LDD3. In [chapter 8](http://www.makelinux.net/ldd3/chp-8-sect-4), I could not understand this paragraph:

> An example of a function in the kernel that uses `vmalloc` is the `create_module` system
>   call, which uses `vmalloc` to get space for the module being created. Code and data of
>   the module are later copied to the allocated space using `copy_from_user`. In this way,
>   the module appears to be loaded into contiguous memory.

Why is `copy_from_user` used? Aren't we in kernel space only?

Answer (score 3):

Recall that kernel modules are loaded by the `insmod` (or `modprobe`) command, which runs in user space. These commands load the kernel module from disk into memory, then pass it to the kernel, which must use `copy_from_user()` to copy that to kernel memory.